# Sending data in POST request (application/xml) in integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing

I'm trying to test my Grape::API with an integration test in `specs/requests`

I'm only using RSpec, not capybara or anything.

I'm simply trying to post data in my integration spec and I keep getting `undefined method 'to_sym'`

This is what I have so far

```
    before do
      post "/v1/users", { :user => {
        :username => "testuser", :password => "pass", :password_confirmation => "pass" } 
      }.to_xml, @api_key.merge({'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/xml'})
    end
```

`@api_key merely` holds the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header

What am I doing wrong here? I've been fighting with this for hours :(

Stack trace:

```
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:74:in `content_type_for'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/formatter.rb:29:in `before'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:19:in `call'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:25:in `call!'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:19:in `call'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:44:in `block in call!'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:43:in `catch'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:43:in `call!'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:19:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:113:in `call!'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:103:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/api.rb:404:in `call'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/api.rb:51:in `call!'
grape (0.2.1.1) lib/grape/api.rb:47:in `call'
```

Comment: Can you post a stack trace for the error?

Comment: added. as a side note how can i show a stack trace within an integration test? it only keeps outputting all the HTML and its very difficult to see

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the version of grape that you are using - try updating to the latest (`0.4.1` at this time).

Comment: very odd... I have `gem 'grape'` in my gemfile?

Comment: Man thanks so much. this took forever to find damnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the version you are using - update to the latest version of grape to fix this problem (`0.4.1` at this time).

Comment: Thanks! Good eyes, I dont think I would have caught that